# Extract tokens from string

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, token

I have a html file, with unknown ammount of tokens. The keywords will be assigned to some data later by the user. I want to determine how much token does the html contain.
Tokens can look like : ¤SomeID¤ or ¤Name¤ or even ¤SomeLongerWord¤.

Can somebody give me a complete code with regex, that would collect the tokens into a list from a string?

Example:

```
string ExtractFromThis = "Hello ¤Name¤, do you speak ¤SomeLanguage¤?"
List<string> IldLikeToHave = Magic(ExtractFromThis); 
//IldLikeToHave should contain {"¤Name¤", "¤SomeLanguage¤"}
```

Thank you!

Comment: For reference on regular expressions, see [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: I did this with some manual spliting, joining, absolutely inefficient code. I know It can be done with regex, unfortunately I don't understand it yet.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: C#, I added the tag later, sorry.

Comment: Have you thought about using the `string.Split()` method

Comment: @DJKRAZE What do you mean? I want to collect the tokens, I can't split  if I don't know what tokens to expect. All I know is that the token starts with ¤ and ends with ¤. There can be anything in between.

Comment: You could use a simple regular expression such as `¤.*?¤` (notice the non-greedy star) matching anything enclosed in `¤`. Here's a [sample](http://regexr.com?345un). You could use [`Regex.Matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx) to get all the matches.

Comment: you have the Token, its that funky looking symbol that you have Name and SomeLanguage wrapped around .. can't you use RegEx's `Regex.Split()` Function..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thank you for your help, it's solved now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a simple regular expression such as `¤.*?¤` (notice the non-greedy star) matching anything enclosed in `¤`. Here's a [sample](http://regexr.com/?345un). You could use [Regex.Matches()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx) to get all the matches.

If you're interested in getting the text inside the delimiters, you could as well put the quantifier inside a capture group like this `¤(.*?)¤`, and use [`Match.Groups()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) to get the capture groups of every match.

I don't do C#, but here's a sample of what it should probably look like:

```
string pattern = @"¤(.*?)¤";
string input = "Hello ¤Name¤, do you speak ¤SomeLanguage¤?";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
List<string> l = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in matches) {
     l.add(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: How would you exclude the delimiters?